# How can i call a webpage after verifying the login form in PHP?

Tags: php

I created a login page where the verification process is done successfully by sending the message. But i want to open webpage by clicking the login buttton for the valid  user.

```
 if ($password != $pass)\\\\ .....comparing the password
                {
               echo"Please Register your details";\\\\...error message 
                } 

                else{
                header("Location=https://www.google.com/www.funworld.com/");\\valid user can enter into this website
                }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Location` header isn't formatted correctly.  Use a colon, not an equals:

```
header("Location: https://www.google.com/www.funworld.com/");
```

A few things of note:

1. This Google URL doesn't exist, so if this is what you're actually using then you're not redirecting the user anywhere useful.
2. I recommend a more specific error than `"Please Register your details"`.  If the user *has* registered and simply didn't login correctly this could be confusing.
3. `if ($password != $pass)`... *Please* tell me you're not storing user passwords in plain text and are properly hashing them.  I know I *technically* don't have reason to believe this, but it does seem likely that you're using plain text passwords.  For the sake of anybody else reading this... There is *no* reason to store user passwords in plain text.  *Ever*.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($password != $pass)\\\\ .....comparing the password
            {
           echo"Please Register your details";\\\\...error message 
            } 

            else{
            header("Location:https://www.google.com/www.funworld.com/");\\valid user can enter into this website
            }
}
```

try that (Notice the '=' was changed to a colon in the header function)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*if user is valid(after fetching data from database) */
header("location:pagename.php ");
 else
 echo"incorrect username/password";
```